# React owl-corusel show only fitted items

Tags: css, reactjs, owl-carousel

I am using owl-corusel in my React Project. I have a problem, the problem is that if an owl-item doesn't fit right on the screen I don't want it to show up. Just center and show how many items appear complete.

[image]

Here is my React code :

```
 <OwlCarousel
            className="owl-theme"
            dots={false}
            loop={true}
            margin={2}
            nav={true}
            items={categoryTags.length}
            autoWidth={true}
            center={true}
          >
            {categoryTags
              ? categoryTags.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="item" key={`tag_item_${item.id}`}>
                      <Link style={{ width: "100%" }} to={"/c/" + item.slug}>
                        <img
                          src={item.avatar_url}
                          alt={item.title}
                          className="full_height full_height"
                        />
                        <div className="flex align_center cat_ico_hover full_width full_height justify_center">
                          <i
                            className="cat_ico"
                            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.icon_url})` }}
                          ></i>
                          <span>{item.label}</span>
                        </div>
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </OwlCarousel>
```